# Web Counter logical statement

Tags: php

Pardon me by the way I will ask this question, I'm a newbie on this site.

Im trying to record number of vistors who visited my website (web counter) **erveryday**!

My logic is `if $date(realtime)` is equal to the $dateDB(max(adddate))`<- (column in my database) then web counter will add 1...
If not it will insert new data then add 1(IT MEANS ANOTHER DAY).

```
<?php 
    $dateDB = mssql_query("select adddate = max(CONVERT(DateTime,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Adddate,101)))from tbl_web_counter");
        if($date == $dateDB){
            mssql_query("update tbl_web_counter SET webcounter_dealerview = webcounter_dealerview + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM tbl_web_counter)");
        }else{
            mssql_query("insert into tbl_web_counter (webcounter_dealerView) values (1) ");
        }
    ?>
```

The update function is running well, however If the statement is false (which is $date is not equal to $dateDB(max(adddate))

"IT STILL UPDATING THE MAX(ADDDATE) NOT INSERTING NEW RECORDS"
"**IT MEANS THAT MY SYNTAX DID NOT PROCEED TO **ELSE***!*"

its is my syntax is wrong?

Comment: It is impossible to tell whether you syntax is correct or not. Provide us some actual code you have been writing.

Comment: you sure with this? if($date = $dateDB), I think it should be if($date == $dateDB)

Comment: see my answer below, your syntax is completly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure with ($date = $dateDB)? Because $dateDB is resource of your select query.

You have to use mssql_fetch_assoc, to fetch date from resource, and then compare it with == operator and after that use update or insert into table.

Comment: It should be neither. `$dateDB` is a query resource, not a date.

Comment: @gerXpaulLlames: Maybe you think it's beyond what you want, but that's why your code doesn't work, because it's _not_.

Comment: ... and then you ruined it by writing `I think it should be ($date == $dateDB)`, which is completely false.

Comment: First, I said there has to be ==, not =, and after I said, $dateDB is resource, not date value...

Comment: Yes, and you said `I think it should be ($date == $dateDB)`, which is wrong. Your answer contradicts itself. Instead of going in circles in the comments, perhaps consider fixing the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Legionar how can I use mssql_fetch_assoc, its like this $sample=mssql_fetch_assoc($dateDB) or like this $dateDB = mssql_fetch_assoc("SELECT..............")?????

Comment: $sample=mssql_fetch_assoc($dateDB), the parameter is resource got in mssql_query

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give a tip over here, not exactly an answer (but related to the heading), but will help you.

Always record the IP of the visitor and the date and make IP address + date combo as a unique key. This would help you in maintaining correct unique count of visitors visiting your website. This also prevents logging of number of refreshes made by the user. i.e each time the user refreshes your page, the counter will go up.

Comment: Should be a comment, and is all that bold really necessary?

Comment: Your tip is actually wrong, as IP is not at all useful as a unique identifier for a visitor.